Why MailKit embedded image in Html body is also showing as attachment?
When I am trying to send a mail using MailKit that has a html body with embedded images, the images are showing in the email body but also as attachments.

I don't want attachments, just as mail body like the following

The code for my mailbody composition is as follows:
 private async Task<MimeMessage> MailCompose(Command request)
 {
     var to = request.EmailAddresses.Select(x => MailboxAddress.Parse(x));
     var message = new MimeMessage();
     message.From.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(request.MailSettingsRequest.SMTPEmailID));
     message.To.AddRange(to);
     message.Subject = request.EmailTemplateRequest.TemplateSubject;

     message.Body = UpdateImageTags(request.EmailTemplateRequest.MessageBody).ToMessageBody();
     return message;
 }
 static BodyBuilder UpdateImageTags(string input)
 {
     var bodyBuilder = new BodyBuilder();
     string pattern = @"<img[^>]*\s+src=['""]([^'""]+)['""][^>]*>"; // Regex to match <img> tags and extract src
     MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

     foreach (Match match in matches)
     {
         string imgTag = match.Value;
         string srcValue = match.Groups[1].Value;

         // Check if src is base64
         if (srcValue.StartsWith("data:image/"))
         {
             // Extract base64 string
             string base64Data = srcValue.Substring(srcValue.IndexOf(",") + 1);
             string imageFormat = srcValue.Substring(5, srcValue.IndexOf(";") - 5); // Get image format (e.g., png, jpeg)

             // Convert base64 to linked resource and add to BodyBuilder
             byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Data);
             var stream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);

             var id = MimeUtils.GenerateMessageId();
             var newpart = new MimePart()
             {
                 ContentId = id,
                 Content = new MimeContent(stream),
                 ContentDisposition = new ContentDisposition(ContentDisposition.Inline),
                 ContentTransferEncoding = ContentEncoding.Base64
             };
             
             bodyBuilder.LinkedResources.Add(newpart);
             
             string newImgTag = $"<img src='cid:{id}' />"; 
            
             input = input.Replace(imgTag, newImgTag);
         }
     }
     bodyBuilder.HtmlBody = input;
     return bodyBuilder;
 }


And sample MessageBody that I am getting from the editor is(the full image byte is omitted for brevity)-
"<p>this is a image email</p>\n<p><img src=\"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoA..."></p>
Edit: Got it working. The updated code is posted below.

Maybe consider reverting the code and putting the fix as an answer below. As it stands, this is no longer a valid question and will likely be closed. If you change it to a question+answer it will benefit people in the future (and improve your SO score).

I got it working by my passing two parameters in the MimePart constructor, the first is "image" and the second is imageformat that I extracted but did not use.
Also I noticed that I was entirely replacing the  tags other attributes when creating a new tag with the generated ContentId, so I improved that code bit as well.
static BodyBuilder UpdateImageTags(string input)
{
   var bodyBuilder = new BodyBuilder();
   string pattern = @"<img[^>]*\s+src=['""]([^'""]+)['""][^>]*>";
   MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    string imgTag = match.Value;
    string srcValue = match.Groups[1].Value;
    
    if (srcValue.StartsWith("data:image/"))
    {
        string base64Data = srcValue.Substring(srcValue.IndexOf(",") + 1);
        string imageFormat = srcValue.Substring(5, srcValue.IndexOf(";") - 5).Split('/')[1]; 

        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Data);
        var stream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);

        var id = MimeUtils.GenerateMessageId();
        var newpart = new MimePart("image", imageFormat)
        {
            ContentId = id,
            Content = new MimeContent(stream),
            ContentDisposition = new ContentDisposition(ContentDisposition.Inline),
            ContentTransferEncoding = ContentEncoding.Base64
        };

        bodyBuilder.LinkedResources.Add(newpart);

        string newImgTag = Regex.Replace(imgTag, @"src=['""][^'""]+['""]", $"src='cid:{id}'");

        input = input.Replace(imgTag, newImgTag);
    }
}
bodyBuilder.HtmlBody = input;
return bodyBuilder;
}

